# Upgrade to SDL Web 8.5 queries

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa, web8.5, upgrade

We have requirement to upgrade SDL Tridion platform from SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 to SDL Web 8.5, along with this we also need to upgrade DXA .NET from 1.0 to 1.8.

Kindly provide your suggestion, tips or any article which helps doing this activity smoothly.

Thanks
Piyush Jain

Answer (score 1):

Please try below User SDL Guideline for Upgrade SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 to SDL Web 8.5

[Upgrade to SDL Web 8.5 from SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1 or SDL Web 8 with Cumulative Update 1 applied.](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-E6995D0C-804C-4399-8EB1-044E64C33A12&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-773A24CE-20C5-47C2-BB72-A8266774D23A.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-E6995D0C-804C-4399-8EB1-044E64C33A12)

[Upgrade from a previous version of DXA by upgrading the Content Manager-side software and the Web application (.NET or Java). The current version is SDL Digital Experience Accelerator 1.8.](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20DXA-v7.1.1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-7BBD251F-E5AB-4A40-B57A-51E3F7635C17&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-7BBD251F-E5AB-4A40-B57A-51E3F7635C17.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-7BBD251F-E5AB-4A40-B57A-51E3F7635C17)